# Reduce space between subfigure and the subfigure captions

Tags: spacing, floats, captions, subfloats

How can I reduce the space between subfigure and the sufigure captions ?

Preamble

```
\usepackage{float}%exact location 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigures
```

Example.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pictures/pic0.pdf}
                \caption{}
                \label{fig:lab0}
        \end{subfigure}       
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pictures/pic1.pdf}
                \caption{}
                \label{fig:lab1}
        \end{subfigure}

        \caption{A long caption}\label{fig:lab} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It is not clear from the context which space between figure and captions you are trying to reduce. Do you mean those created by the `\caption{}` commands in subfigure? But you have kept them empty, leaving one to misunderstand.

Comment: Leaving empty allows one to number the subfigure with (a), (b) and so on. if I remove those, then the subfigures are not numbered.

Comment: That was not my point. It is obvious that if you leave them blank, only the subfigure numbers will be generated. But when you say "reduce the space between subfigure and the sufigure captions", that makes one wonder, whether this is the vertical space between individual figures and subfigure captions, or whether this is the vertical space before the main caption. Anyway, looks like you have received some excellent answers and comments. These should be useful to all of us.

Comment: My understanding is, the individual subfigures make the overall 'figure'. So, there are two types of captions, 1) Subfigure caption 2) Figure caption. My problem was with the subfigure caption. I could have added the word 'individual' may be to make it more clear.

Answer (score 18):

#### Method 1: `\vspace`

Place a `\vspace` command after the last figure and before the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float} % figure [H]
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigures

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                \caption{}
                \label{fig:lab0}
        \end{subfigure}       
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
                \label{fig:lab1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
        \caption{A long caption}\label{fig:lab} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You probably don't want to use the value `-2\baselineskip` as I have done.  I've only done that so you can readily see the effect below:

[image]

---

#### Method 2: `\aboveskip` and `\belowskip`

Per the comments to this post, there is an `aboveskip` and `belowskip` option available via the `caption` package, which is loaded when loading `subcaption`.  This allows you to more conveniently make a change to how the captions are placed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}%exact location 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigures

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \captionsetup[subfigure]{aboveskip=-1pt,belowskip=-1pt}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                \caption{}
                \label{fig:lab0}
        \end{subfigure}       
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
                \label{fig:lab1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{A long caption}\label{fig:lab} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The better way is to use the `aboveskip` option for the »[subcaption](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)« package. By the way it was asked for the reduction of space between sub-figures and sub-captions, not between the sub-figures and the main caption.

Comment: This reduces the space between the main CAPTION and the last subfigure. I want to reduce the space between all the 'subcaptions' to the corresponding subfigures.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I wasn't aware of such an option.  I don't see it in the documentation either.

Comment: @cosmicraga You can do the same thing within each subfigure.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig. Thanks. It works. I need to add `\captionsetup{aboveskip=-5pt, belowskip=5pt}' before the \caption{} of the subfigures.

Comment: @A.Ellett: It takes nearly the same options as »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)«. Settings for sub-figures are done by `\captionsetup` internally.

Comment: @A.Ellett `\captionsetup[subfigure]{aboveskip=1pt}` which can be global (in the preamble) or local (in the `figure` environment, before any `subfigure`).

Comment: @cosmicraga: Just use `\usepackage[aboveskip=2pt]{subcaption}`.