# No space between rows and columns of subfigures

Tags: spacing

I have created a 3x3 matrix of figures as follow:

```
\begin{figure} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure}    & 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure}   & 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure}  \\ 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure}   & 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure}  & 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure} \\ 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure}    &  
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure}    &  
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{my_figure}   \\ 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Many figures}
\end{figure}
```

How can I reduce or leave no space among them?

Comment: `\begin{figure}\tabcolsep=0pt\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks but didn't work.

Comment: Then please make your code compilable. Show us a minimal example of what you have. My approach works perfectly for me in `article`.

Comment: "Didn't work" is nothing we can work with. What does not work, the rows, the columns, both, getting an error...?

Comment: It is part of my thesis and the template is from the university so I cannot specify the `document class` . It didn't reduce the space,  both between the rows and columns, no errors though.

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is: Try a standard document class. If it still does not work, you have to find the settings which are disturbing here and show them to us. We can not guess what is happening. If it does work with a standard class, we will have to take a look on that template-class of yours.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it in `article` and works fine indeed. I can provide a link about the template of the university [https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzhgoucl6emmr94/kulemt-1.8a-src%20%282%29.zip?dl=0] .

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132956/reduce-space-between-subfigure-and-the-subfigure-captions?rq=1

Comment: Instead of `scale=0.2` I recommend using `width=...` for better control; since you have three images per row, using `width=0.25\columnwidth` seems good: there will be 1/8 of the column width at either side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As LaRiFaRi suggested `\newcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}` supresses space between rows and `@{}` between columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{@{}c}@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}    & 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}   & 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}  \\
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}   & 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}  & 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image} \\
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}    &  
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}    &  
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}   
\end{tabular}
\caption{Many figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd option:** with `raster` library from [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

`raster` library allows you to arrange several boxes in a regular way. By default, every row occupies the whole line width and `tcolorbox` calculates inner tcolorboxes size.

Instead of `\includegraphics` you must use `\tcbincludegraphics` because `raster` environment expects `tcolorboxes`. `tcolorbox` options can be used: `title`, colors, etc. and also special options to `\includegrahics` command can be indicated with `graphics={...}`. You can also decide distance between rows and columns.

The code for this particular case could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster equal height, 
raster column skip=0pt, raster row skip=0pt, raster every box/.style={blank}]
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\end{tcbraster}
\caption{Many figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `\begin{tabular}*{3}{@{}c}@{}}` for suppressing also the trailing padding; otherwise the centering is not correct.

Comment: Your approach is working great in the document classes of latex. However, because I am writing my thesis in a template of my university (I share the link in a comment), I have incompatibility problems. It runs but doesn't give any result.

Comment: @DimKoim I've opened your zip file, included all *.sty, *.cls files inside `/kulemnt/doc/template` folder, inserted my example from `\begin{figure}` to `\end{figure}` between two `\include{...}` lines in `thesis.tex` and everything worked as expected. Unless you provide some more information we cannot help you.

Comment: I dunno what's the problem with my template but your answer is more than correct.  No, I don't have any more info to provide. Thanks a lot.