# How to adjust the gap between figure and caption in subfloat

Tags: captions, subfloats

For the following example:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[ scale=0.5]{images/a.jpg}}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/b.jpg}}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \caption{}\label{fig:online_test}
\end{figure}
```

I got the following figure:

[image]

The sub-caption of (a) is too close to the sub-figure B. How can I adjust the space between the caption and figure within a `subfloat`?

Thank you all for helping me and I would prefer a solution for `subfloat`, instead of using other packages. But I would also appreciate a solution of using other packages.

I know my question looks similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162824/vertical-spacing-between-subfloat). But **please make it clear**. I'm asking for how to adjust the gap between figure and caption **within a `subfloat`**, not the gap **between two `subfloat`**. That is, the **gap between the caption "a" and the figure "A"!!!**

I would keep arguing until my question get re-opened.

Comment: It is the duplicate of this one, then: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132956/101651

Comment: To be fair, you did say "The sub-caption of (a) is too close to the sub-figure B.", which is about the space between one subfloat's caption and the next subfloat. Probably the source of the confusion.

Comment: Have you seen egreg's answer in the linked question?  "with `captionskip` we set the distance from the subfigure and the caption."

Comment: However, Zarko has already answered to your (identical) question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386013/101651

Comment: Thx. Then you may denote this question as a duplicate of my another question. And sorry for bothering because of my failure in making a clear declaration. Thank you so much!